# How to add Stripe payments using Laravel, Cashier and Vue js?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm looking to add Stripe payments to my project. I'm building an SPA using Laravel and Vue js. I see a lot of tutorials on Laravel and Stripe but not very many on Laravel, Stripe and Vue js.

I'm looking for a video or article on how to do this, I'm just not sure if I should try and find something with Vue js or if it is all done on the php side. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you looked into laravel cashier? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/billing

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm using Laravel Cashier as well. I'm taking a course on LinkedIn, but I just realized that he isn't using Vue, so I have questions now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking for free articles, this one is what you're looking for.

[using-laravel-cashier-with-vuejs-spa-and-laravel-passport-api](https://serversideup.net/courses/using-laravel-cashier-with-vuejs-spa-and-laravel-passport-api/)